# How make one way binding for element which changed by any action(which made not by user) in vue.js

Tags: javascript, frameworks, vue.js

I try to use vue.js for creating Interactive preview of my form.

But i haven't custom element for loading image and creating preview for them. I need to bind my hidden input, which changed by handler function to image.

**It's my hidden image, which hold base64 form of the loaded image**

```
 input(type="text" name="logotype" v-model="brandLogo" style="display: none;")#image-attach
```

**My preview element**

```
 img(src="{{brandLogo}}")
```

**Some vue.js setting**

```
var Brand = new Vue({
        el: '#brand',
        data: {
            brandName: 'title of form',
            brandDesc: 'decription of form',
            brandLogo: 'img/logo.png',
            brandColorBg: '#2c6aa2',
            brandColorText: '#fff'
        }
    });
```

But after changed value form of my hidden input element, don't happen to change of my data in Vue.

I suggest, that v-model change element after some action as (typing text in input) but how to observer another actions, which can to apply to elements?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the **input** and the **preview part** are within(inside) the **brand** div

Comment: Yeah, it's really so

Comment: Is input type file or text??  It should be an file type

Comment: It's text, cause after adding file in file input I crop image and put base64 url type in this text input

Comment: @BorisovSemen check my new answer i tried . Hope is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

This is working perfect. When i enter the path on input it automaticall update the image.

```
<div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-model='image.path'>

    <div>
        <img :src="image.path" width="100" height="100">
    </div>

    <pre> {{ $data | json}}</pre>
</div>

<script src="vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    new Vue({
        el:'#app',

        data:{
            image:{
                'name':'',
                'path':''
            }
        }

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```